# Variable scope in SASS each loop

Tags: sass, scope, each

I am trying to generate css class names using an @each loop in SASS and I am facing some confusion regarding the scope of a variable declared within the loop.

The variable `$infix` is meant to prefix the generated class name with a unique break-point-name ('sm','md','lg'...etc), only if the $break-point-width is not = 0

The problem is, the value of the $infix variable, ie, the break-point-name, is the same on each iteration of the loop, although I expected it would be unique per each iteration.

**SCSS**

```
$config: (
        phone: (
                break-point-width:0px,
                break-point-name: xs
        ),
        tablet: (
                break-point-width:600px,
                break-point-name: sm
        ),
        laptop: (
                break-point-width:900px,
                break-point-name: md
        ),
        desktop: (
                break-point-width:1200px,
                break-point-name:lg
        ),
);

@each $key, $map in $config {
  $break-point-width: map_get($map, break-point-width);
  $break-point-name: map_get($map, break-point-name);
  $infix: if($break-point-width == 0px, null, -$break-point-name);
  @media (min-width: $break-point-width) {
    @for $i from 1 through 2 {
      .foo#{$infix}-#{$i} {
        content: 'bar';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Compiled CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 0px) {
  .foo-1 {
    content: 'bar'; }
  .foo-2 {
    content: 'bar'; } }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .foo-sm-1 {
    content: 'bar'; }
  .foo-sm-2 {
    content: 'bar'; } }

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .foo-sm-1 {
    content: 'bar'; }
  .foo-sm-2 {
    content: 'bar'; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .foo-sm-1 {
    content: 'bar'; }
  .foo-sm-2 {
    content: 'bar'; } }
```

As seen in the compiled css output, the first iteration of the loop does not prefix the class name with the value of the $infix variable as was expected. In the remaining iterations all class names are prefixed with the 'sm' break-point-name. This is confusing, as it is seen the value of the $break-point-width variable is unique in each iteration, shown in the generated @media queries, but the value of the $break-point-name variable is the same in each iteration.

I am assuming the $infix variable, hence its value, is not scoped to each iteration of the loop and is only declared once.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand the cause of this behavior and how I could solve this problem.

With much thanks and appreciation,

Comment: I think the problem comes from you compiler because when I try your code on SassMeister the compiled CSS looks correct.

Comment: @Arkellys Thankyou, you are correct, SassMesiter produces the correct output, while using any compiler other than libsass. I am using a webpack/node-sass stack which uses libsass as the compiler and SassMesiter confirmed that it is indeed libsass causing this issue. Thank you very much, this is a huge burden lifted. Now, on to finding a workaround for node-sass/libsass